# Java program to remove new line character from the line

Tags: java, arrays, newline

I am having trouble removing new line character that appears in the line.

**My input is:**

```
1,john,a

2,smith,b

3,mike

,c

4,clark,d
```

**My output should be:**

```
1,john,a

2,smith,b

3,mike,c

4,clark,d
```

Below is the code I wrote so far. I am using "continue" to remove bad records based on count of expected "," in each line. However, I would like to concatenate the line where "\n" exists wrongly with the next line to get the line instead of removing as bad record.

```
String test="1,john,a\n2,smith,b\n3,mike\n,c\n4,clark,d";

String[] test2=test.split("\n");

int count=0;
String s="";
for(int i=0;i<=test2.length-1;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<test2[i].length();j++) {
        char c= test2[i].charAt(j);
        if(c==',') {
           count++;
           if(count<2) {
              continue;
           }
           System.out.println(test2[i]);
        }
    }
    count=0;    
}
```

Comment: Is your input guaranteed to have exactly three (desired) elements per line?

Comment: @markspace yes, it should always have 3 elements in a line

Comment: Does split() not remove the newline character?

Comment: FYI: Any attempt at sanitizing poorly-formatted data after the fact is likely to be flaky. If your input is allowing newlines, are you really certain it's not allowing commas? How do you know "3,mike\n,c\n4,clark,d" means `[[3,"mike","c"],[4,"clark","d"]]` and not `[[3,"mike\n,c,4,clark","d"]]`? If at all possible, the best solution is to change the way these values are getting encoded in the first place.

Comment: Use a regular expression to replace any occurrence of `\n,` or `,\n` with `""`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I think you mean to replace those with `,`. But that assumes that you know the `\n` always appears adjacent to a comma.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Thanks, yes of course I meant to replace with a `,` and yes I assumed that the combination of a comma before/after a new line was the issue here.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. The problem is simply a new line character appearing at wrong place that needs to be removed. Each line should have three elements separated by ",".  Look at the line 1: 1,john,a

Comment: The new line character can appear anywhere, it has nothing do with comma. However, each line in output should have three elements separated by ",". There should be some logic that concatenate the line with the next one if three elements are not returned in that line

Comment: You say the new line character can appear anywhere, so even in the middle of a string, like `1,Mi\nke,b\n`?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson yes

Comment: If you for instance have a record made up of two strings then it would be impossible to know if  the F in `ABC,DE\nF\nGH,IJK\n` should belong to the first or second record, that is `ABC,DEF` or `FGH,JKL`. For your file and record format, can you determine that?

Comment: I got your point. Going back to my string, this is formatted data, the general rule is every line will start with integer and there are no integer values in other two columns. For the issue you noticed, I will need to add another logic to check if the record start with integer, if doesn't start with integer append it to previous line. If record does not start with integer and integer appears later in the same line, then append only portion until integer appears

Answer (score 4):

If you always have exactly three elements per line, try splitting on both `\n` and `,` and then just combine three elements into one line.

```
String test="1,john,a\n2,smith,b\n3,mike\n,c\n4,clark,d";

String[] test2=test.split("[\n,]+");

for(int i=0;i<test2.length;i+=3)
{
   System.out.println(test2[i]+","+test2[i+1]+","+test2[i+2]);
}
```

Comment: Could you just call text2.split() on the string? Won't this break on each newline without specifying the carriage? Just wondering, I dont have JDK on this machine and haven't used Java in some time.

Comment: I don't think this works, as `test.split("[\n,]");` will produce an empty string between "mike" and "c". See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Comment: @markspace Thanks fro the response. However, this code did not return the expected output

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I added a `+` after the bracket, works for me now.  Sorry for posting untested code.

Comment: @mohammedahmed I added a `+` to the regex, try it now.

Comment: @markspace Is there any way we can do it based on count of "," in each line. Each line should have 3 commas, if not concatenate the line with the next one and check again and do so on until line has 3 commas

Comment: My actual file is very large and has around 308 columns and 55,000 records. I have verified that concatenating based on count of "," will fix the issue

Comment: @markspace The `+` only makes it work if the `\n` and `,` are right next to each other. `3,mi\nke,c` would cause you to match the `\n` as a separate delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

```
String test="1,john,a\n2,smith,b\n3,mike\n,c\n4,clark,d";

String[] test2=test.split("\n");

int count=0;
String s="";
for(int i=0;i<=test2.length-1;i++)
{
   String[] temp=test2[i].split(",");
   if(temp.length!=3){
     s=s+test2[i]+test2[i+1]+"\n";
     i++;
   }
else{
    s=s+temp[0]+","+temp[1]+","+temp[2]+"\n";
   }
}
 System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this:

String s="a,b,c\n";

```
while(s != null){ <<<<<-------Use the while condition as per your use case

    String[] var = s.split("\n");

    System.out.println(var[0]);
}
```

and it shows the desired result. You can split all the lines of the file similarly and get the desired output.

Output: a,b,c

Make sure to iterate the loop properly like buffer.readLine()

I hope it helps.